# How to make global reactive variables in Vue 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar

I want to make a reactive prominent global variable in Vue 2

I wish it worked like computed

How to make global reactive variables in Vue 2 ?

Thank you for your reply.

```
import { Screen } from 'quasar';
const isMobileSize = Screen.lt.sm; // <- I want it to be a reactive global variable
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to directly access the reactive global variable in your components:

```
import { Screen } from 'quasar';
Vue.prototype.$isMobileSize = Screen.lt.sm;
```

Then in your components:

```
computed: {
  isMobileSize () {
    return this.$isMobileSize
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
I have one more question.
Is there any way to declare computed globally?

Comment: Hi Evans, I will add it as another answer.

Answer (score 2):

To declare computed globally and be able to use in other components, you can define a global mixin in `main.js`:

```
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    isMobileSize () {
      return Screen.lt.sm
    }
  }
})
```

Then you can use it in any component:

```
computed: {
  isMobileSize () {
    return this.isMobileSize
  }
}
```

Comment: Vue.mixin is a powerful feature of Vue that allows you to inject functionality into all components. A mixin is a JavaScript object containing component options that you can mix into your Vue components. This means that the mixin's options will be merged into the component's own options. This allows you to easily share logic across components. By using mixins, you can easily extract and reuse common parts of your components.